# Code works, but unit test says false, What is going on?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x

If I test both function manually by doing accountant.give_default_raise() or accountant.give_custom_raise() everything works just as it should, yet when I run a unit test it keeps giving me error messages and saying false.

```
class Employee():

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, annual_salary = 3000):
       """Declare the attributes"""
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.annual_salary = annual_salary


    def give_default_raise(self):
        """Add $5,0000 by default to the annual salary, but accept any amount"""
        self.annual_salary += 5000
        new_salary = self.annual_salary
        print(new_salary)

    def give_custom_raise(self):
        """Add a custom amount"""
        custom_raise = input("How much would you like to increase? ")
        self.annual_salary += int(custom_raise)
        new_custom_salary = self.annual_salary
        print(new_custom_salary)


accountant = Employee('John', 'Jones', 120000)
accountant.give_default_raise()

import unittest

class TestEmployee(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test the Employee class"""

    def test_give_default_raise(self):
        accountant = Employee('John', 'Jones', 120000)
        self.assertEqual(annual_salary, 125000)

unittest.main()
```

Comment: What is `annual_salary` in  the `test_give_default_raise()` function?  That variable name does not appear to be defined anywhere.

Comment: You have a global `accountant` and then create a local `accountant` in `test_give_default_raise`. They do no refer to the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your test function should look like this:

```
def test_give_default_raise(self):
    # create a new employee
    accountant = Employee('John', 'Jones', 120000)

    # give him a default raise
    accountant.give_default_raise()

    # verify that the salary was increased by the expected amount
    self.assertEqual(accountant.annual_salary, 125000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how unit tests work. You claim to be testing the unit `give_default_raise()` but never call it.

Change your test to

```
def test_give_default_raise(self):
    accountant = Employee('John', 'Jones', 120000)
    accountant.give_default_raise()
    self.assertEqual(annual_salary, 125000)
```

Also, to make `give_custom_raise()` unit testable as well, you should move the interaction out of it and just pass the raise amount to the method.

Also, have a look at [setUp()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) and [tearDown()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.tearDown). They can save you a lot of work when covering all or most methods of your class with tests.

Comment: @idjaw: I hit my mouse pad while typing it and the answer went out early. ;)

Comment: Deleted my comment when I saw your expanded response. :) Cheers.